# Keras load_model with custom objects doesn't work properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

**Setting**

As already mentioned in the title, I got a problem with my custom loss function, when trying to load the saved model. My loss looks as follows:

```
def weighted_cross_entropy(weights):

    weights = K.variable(weights)

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1-K.epsilon())

        loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
        loss = -K.sum(loss, -1)
        return loss

    return loss

weighted_loss = weighted_cross_entropy([0.1,0.9])
```

So during training, I used the `weighted_loss` function as loss function and everything worked well. When training is finished I save the model as `.h5`file with the standard `model.save` function from keras API.

**Problem**

When I am trying to load the model via

```
model = load_model(path,custom_objects={"weighted_loss":weighted_loss})
```

I am getting a `ValueError` telling me that the loss is unknown.

**Error**

The error message looks as follows:

```
File "...\predict.py", line 29, in my_script
"weighted_loss": weighted_loss})
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 312, in _deserialize_model
sample_weight_mode=sample_weight_mode)
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 139, in compile
loss_function = losses.get(loss)
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 133, in get
return deserialize(identifier)
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 114, in deserialize
printable_module_name='loss function')
File "...\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\processing\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 165, in deserialize_keras_object
':' + function_name)
ValueError: Unknown loss function:loss
```

**Questions**

How can I fix this problem? May it be possible that the reason for that is my wrapped loss definition? So `keras` doesn't know, how to handle the `weights` variable?

Comment: Could you please include the full error log/stack trace?

Comment: Of course. I added the full message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your loss function's name is `loss` (i.e. `def loss(y_true, y_pred):`). Therefore, when loading back the model you need to specify `'loss'` as its name:

```
model = load_model(path, custom_objects={'loss': weighted_loss})
```

Answer (score -1):

For full examples demonstrating **saving and loading Keras models with custom loss functions or models**, please have a look at the following GitHub gist files:

Custom loss function defined using a wrapper:
https://gist.github.com/ashkan-abbasi66/a81fe4c4d588e2c187180d5bae734fde

Custom loss function defined by subclassing:
https://gist.github.com/ashkan-abbasi66/327efe2dffcf9788847d26de934ef7bd

Custom model:
https://gist.github.com/ashkan-abbasi66/d5a525d33600b220fa7b095f7762cb5b

Note:
I tested the above examples on Python 3.8 with Tensorflow 2.5.

Comment: Please avoid to answer by only providing links. They can expire.