# Error When Trying to Calculate FLOPS for Complex TF2 Keras Models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I want to calculate the FLOPS in the ML models used. I get an error when I tried to calculate for much complex models.

I get this Error for Efficientnet Models:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: FixedDropout. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
​
```

The function to calculate the FLOPS:

1)

```
def get_flops(model, batch_size=None):
    if batch_size is None:
        batch_size = 1

    real_model = tf.function(model).get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec([batch_size] + model.inputs[0].shape[1:], model.inputs[0].dtype))
    frozen_func, graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(real_model)

    run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
    opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
    flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=frozen_func.graph,
                                            run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
    return flops.total_float_ops
```

or

2)

```
def get_flops(model_h5_path):
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
        

    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
        
            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
        
            return flops.total_float_ops
```

On the contrary, I am able to calculate the FLOPS for models like Resnets, just that it is not possible for bit complex models. How can I mitigate the issue?

Comment: Which line produces the error? Is it load_model?

Comment: You're probably working with the official implementation of efficientnet. In either way, you need to load efficientnet model with custom object, here that is FixedDropout. See how https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223449/9215780.

Comment: Error occurs in the profiler

Comment: The model loads fine